# Raspberry Pi Graphics via ssh and local

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, x11

I have a raspberry pi with a code that has a graphical output using OpenGL. When I'm ssh'ed in, I get the X window output of the graphic. When I run it on the pi however, the output doesn't show up. Does anyone have any ideas?

I've compared the printenv details for both, and everything except ssh is the same. It's running "raspbian wheezy" - "Linux raspberrypi 3.2.27+ #160 PREEMPT Mon Sep 17 23:18:42 BST 2012 armv6l GNU/Linux "

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to trace X11 calls your program is making using tracer like [xtruss](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/xtruss/)

OpenGL on X11 works differently for local and non-local connections.
For local connections:

- [client asks DRI2 extension](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/glx/indirect_glx.c) to allocate video memory buffer
- all further requests are local function calls, OpenGL library -> video driver -> kernel, bypassing X server

For non-local connections - each GL command is corresponding request in [GLX extension](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/proto/tree/src/glx.xml?id=HEAD)

Also see [DRI wiki docs](http://www.x.org/wiki/DRI2)

Comment: Just saw this now, I'll give this a try soon... Thanks!